# Desktop folder keeps reverting to read-only. Using Visual Studio 2022 and Windows 10 Home

Tags: c#, windows-10, visual-studio-2022

I'm using my personal PC and have tried and successfully implemented all of the recommended fixes, including adding a manifest item to my program with "", Run DISM (Deployment Image Servicing and Management) and SFC (System File Checker) scans, disabling controlled folder access, running as an admin, modifying the attributes of the folder, and changing the permissions of my main drive. I've also restarted multiple times as well and checked to make sure the system-level changes stuck (they did). However every time, I check the File folder properties, the Read-only box is once again blackened in. Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved adding a blank text file to the folder in question.